# How can I visual select a ruby module?

Tags: visual-mode

Assuming I have the following:

```
My::Cool::Klass.call(args)
Cool::Klass.call(args)
```

Is there anyway I can visually select either the `My::Cool::Klass` or the `Cool::Klass` with a quick command?

Note: These are examples, so the strings could be different with two or more nodes (i.e. constants surrounding the `::` symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cursor is at the start of the class, then `vt.` should work. If it’s anywhere else in the example text then just jump to the start first: `Bvt.`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby very well so I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but if you want to search for strings which are always in the form of `aword` followed one time or more by `::anotherword` you can use the following search pattern:

```
\w\+\(::\w\+\)\+
```

This should be pretty straightforward to read:

```
\w\+              One or more (\+) word characters (\w)
    \(      \)\+  Followed by at least one capture group...
      ::          ...containing two litteral ':'...
        \w\+      ...followed by one or more (\+) word characters (\w)
```